# an equivalent expression of (a&&b) without using && operator

Tags: java

considering the expression(a&&b), I am trying to write an equivalent expression (that evaluates to true for same values of a and b) without using && operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like

```
!(!a || !b)
```

Comment: yes its working properly.

Comment: +1, [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws)

Comment: Why the down vote? Please tell me how this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 5):

you should use :

```
a ? b : false

if a is true , return value will be b (b =>false return false , b=>true return true)
if a is false , return value will be false
```

Answer (score 3):

How about nested ternary conditionals?

```
a ? b ? true : false : false
```

Example code:

```
public class A {
        public static boolean and(boolean a, boolean b) {
                return a ? b ? true : false : false;
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                System.out.println(and(false, false));
                System.out.println(and(false, true));
                System.out.println(and(true, false));
                System.out.println(and(true, true));
        }
}
```

Output:

```
false
false
false
true
```

Comment: Which you can shorten to `a ? b : false`

Comment: It does appear to work, in the example code I've added.

Comment: it seems so. can you explain this line a?b?true:false:false;